# radar chart with boxplot

Tags: javascript, data-visualization, charts

I have a radar/spider chart.

The input to this chart can be in the format as shown:

```
[23, 34, 54, [4, 3, 67], 45, 5]
```

When there is a single value, it is shown as a data point, but when it is an array of points, I want the data to be shown in a boxplot instead (as in the image shown below).

My question is which javascript library is suitable for this type of requirement? I tried using 'Highcharts', but I could not get the boxplot.

[image]